# CKEditor spellchecker - what are my options for ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ckeditor, spell-checking

I am looking to use CKEditor in ASP MVC application. I have been having a quick look around and it would seem that my only spellchecking options are to use a plugin for the browser (IE8) or use Spellchecker.net.

Does anybody have any other suggestions on how to add spellchecking to CKEditor/IE8?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We looked for a long time to find a reasonable spell checking substitute for ckeditor. We finally arrived at [NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/). It's a managed wrapper around [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/), which is a very popular spell checking library used in OpenOffice, FireFox 3, etc.

The API is quite simple, so it's just a matter of writing a plugin to perform the spellchecking.